# Conditional Linq Select on Nested object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given I have a simple object like this

```
public class TestA
{
    public int TestAId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestB> TestBCollection { get; set; }
}

public class TestB
{
    public int TestBId { get; set; }
    public int FkTestAId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

List<TestA> a = new List<TestA>()
            {
                new TestA()
                {
                    TestAId = 1,
                    Description = "Test A Description",
                    TestBCollection = new List<TestB>()
                    {
                        new TestB()
                        {
                            TestBId = 10,
                            FkTestAId = 1,
                            Description = "Test B Description" // this must be used because of the matching FK
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

I am trying to `Select` the `description` property on `TestA` but if there is a value in `TestB` where `TestAId == FkTestAId` I want to select `TestB` Description

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `DefaultIfEmpty` overload to use `a.Decription` if there is no matching `b.Description`:

```
var descriptions = a
    .Select(x => x.TestBCollection
        .Where(b => b.FkTestAId == x.TestAId)
        .Select(b => b.Description)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(x.Description)
        .First());
```

`First` is safe here and will never throw an exception because i have specified a fallback value for the case the there was no matching item in "sub-query", so `FirstOrDefault` is unnecessary.

---

Additional requirement mentioned in a comment:

> I want it to default if the record does not exist or if `Description`
>   in `TestB` is `null` or empty

Then you need to modify the inner `Where`:

```
.Where(b => b.FkTestAId == x.TestAId && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Description))
```